# How to fix error get app version on Android 12?

Tags: android

I used this code and it can only get the version of other app above Android 11 and earlier. On Android 12 it doesn't work.

```
String uri = "com.uptodown.installer";

android.content.pm.PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); try { android.content.pm.PackageInfo pInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(uri, android.content.pm.PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES); String version = pInfo.versionName;textview.setText(version); } catch (android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) { }
```

I tried to try but it only works on Android 11 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, `getPackageInfo()` is deprecated as you've used it. From the ide:

```
Deprecated
Use getPackageInfo(String, PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags) instead.
```